# Create Foreach Statement inside While Loop

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, while-loop

I am trying to send out emails based on specific results pulled from my database. I'm trying to do a `foreach` statement inside my `while` loop to send out an email for each result, but I am only getting one result to come out even though I know there should be more than one.

Here is my call to the database and my `while` loop:

```
//get USER info
$getTenant = $db->query("SELECT user_fname, user_lname, user_email FROM users WHERE user_id={$user_id}");
$tenant = $getTenant->fetch_array();

$user_fname = $tenant['user_fname'];
$user_lname = $tenant['user_lname'];
$user_email = $tenant['user_email']; 

// SELECT statement for RENTALS.
    $getRentals = $db->query("SELECT rental_id, user_id, unit_id, rental_renewdate, rental_balance FROM rentals");


// Search each result to send email
while($rental = $getRentals->fetch_assoc()) {

    $rental_id = $rental['rental_id'];
    $user_id = $rental['user_id'];
    $unit_id = $rental['unit_id'];
    $rental_renewdate = strtotime($rental['rental_renewdate']);
    $rental_balance = $rental['rental_balance'];
```

And here is my attempt at creating a `foreach` statement to send out an email for each row that gets pulled:

```
  if ($today == $notify_prior) {

        // SELECT statement for EMAILS for PRIOR.

        $getPrior = $db->query("SELECT email_subject, email_h1, email_body, email_fromemail FROM emails WHERE email_id=1");
        $prior = $getPrior->fetch_array();

        $email_subject = $prior['email_subject'];
        $email_h1 = $prior['email_h1'];
        $email_body = $prior['email_body'];
        $email_fromemail = $prior['email_fromemail'];

        $getPrior->close();

        foreach ($getRentals as $prior_warnings){
            $prior_warnings[] = array($rental_id, $user_fname, $user_lname, $user_email);

            /* PRIOR NOTIFICATION CUSTOMER EMAIL*/

            $to       = '$user_email';
            $subject  = $email_subject;
            $headers  = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n';
            $headers .= 'From: '. $email_fromemail . '\r\n' . 'Reply-To: '. $email_fromemail . '\r\n' . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
            $message  = '<p>'. $user_fname .','. $user_lname .'</p>
            <h1>'. $email_h1 .'</h1>
            <p>'. str_replace(array("{UNIT_NUMBER}","{DUE_DATE}"), array($unit['unit_number'],date('m-d-Y',$rental_renewdate)), stripslashes($email_body)) .'</p>';
            mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        }

    }
}
```

The only thing I seemed to have accomplished is creating an infinite loop that sends tons of emails out for one guy.

Comment: You're using `$getRentals` as your argument in the foreach loop... should you be using `$rental` instead?

Comment: I made that change because you're right but I still get just "Array" with no values when dumping the variable $prior_warnings.

Comment: and just before anyone asks: yes the database connection works. Other data gets pulled in just fine so that's not the issue.